# Snowplow: Warning: No tracker configured

Tags: javascript, jquery, snowplow

I am facing problem during interrelation of snowplow to my angular app I am following official documentation from here [enter link description here](https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow/wiki/1-General-parameters-for-the-Javascript-tracker?_sp=22eb4d03-cb7f-4b5e-9f9a-a0b0404351f9.1464331304831)

My code is

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    ;(function(p,l,o,w,i,n,g){if(!p[i]){p.GlobalSnowplowNamespace=p.GlobalSnowplowNamespace||[];
p.GlobalSnowplowNamespace.push(i);p[i]=function(){(p[i].q=p[i].q||[]).push(arguments)
};p[i].q=p[i].q||[];n=l.createElement(o);g=l.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];n.async=1;
n.src=w;g.parentNode.insertBefore(n,g)}}(window,document,"script","http://d1fc8wv8zag5ca.cloudfront.net/2.6.1/sp.js","snowplow_tracker"));

      console.debug(snowplow_tracker);

    snowplow_tracker('gotoTrackerMethode', '{{MY-COLLECTOR-URI (cloudFront URl)}}');
    function gotoTrackerMethode(a, b)
    {
        console.debug(a);
    }
    function gotoTrackerName(s){
      console.debug("asdf");
    }
    // window.snowplow_tracker('enableActivityTracking', 30, 10);
    // window.snowplow_tracker('enableLinkClickTracking');
    // window.snowplow_tracker('trackPageView');
    </script>
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of R&D i find the solution myself which is you need to invoke callback method not simple but callback like

```
 ;(function(p,l,o,w,i,n,g){if(!p[i]){p.GlobalSnowplowNamespace=p.GlobalSnowplowNamespace||[];
p.GlobalSnowplowNamespace.push(i);p[i]=function(){(p[i].q=p[i].q||[]).push(arguments)
};p[i].q=p[i].q||[];n=l.createElement(o);g=l.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];n.async=1;
n.src=w;g.parentNode.insertBefore(n,g)}}(window,document,"script","http://d1fc8wv8zag5ca.cloudfront.net/2.6.1/sp.js","snowplow_tracker"));


    // callbacks
  snowplow_tracker(function () {
    console.log("sp.js has loaded");
  });

  snowplow_tracker(function (x) {
    console.log(x);
  }, "sp.js has loaded");


  //Find the utma cookie and extract the unique user ID
  function getGoogleId() {
      var id, a, c = document.cookie.split('; ');
      for (var i in c) {
          a = c[i].split('=');
          if (a[0]==='__utma') {
              id = a[1].split('.')[1];
          }
      }
      return id || 'unknown';
  }


        // Configure a tracker instance named "cf"
  snowplow_tracker('newTracker', 'cf', 'd3rkrsqld9gmqf.cloudfront.net', {
      appId: 'snowplowExampleApp',
      platform: 'web'
  });

  // Access the tracker instance inside a callback
  snowplow_tracker(function () {
      var cf = this.cf;
      var userFingerprint = cf.getUserFingerprint();
       var domainUserId = cf.getDomainUserId();
       var domainUserInfo = cf.getDomainUserInfo();
       var userId = cf.getUserId();
      console.debug(userId);
      console.debug(domainUserInfo);
      console.debug(userFingerprint);
      console.debug(domainUserId);
  })

   snowplow_tracker('enableActivityTracking', 30, 10);
  snowplow_tracker('enableLinkClickTracking');
  snowplow_tracker('trackPageView');
```

This is working fine now.